# window.history.go() with an url not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a `Home`button on my html page but I cannot get it to work.

This home button should always load the home page, but it should load it from the cache.
The reason for that is there a number of checkboxes on the home page and when  I do `window.location = "myhomepage"` the page is reloaded in stead of loaded from cache, and all the checked checkboxes are empty again as are other input values.

I found that `window.history.back()` does not always works well when the user opened other pages before hitting the back button.
So I tried with `window.history.go("myhomepage")` but that does nothing at all. The page remains the same.

I have read the docs at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp but it does not seem to work.
My homepage is currently "http://localhost/test/index.php" so it tried it with this

```
windows.history.go("http://localhost/test/index.php")
```

but it does nothing at all.
I also tried variations like
  `.go("localhost/test/index.php")`
  `.go("localhost/test")`
but they all seem to do absolutly nothing at all.

Is there a special trick to get the `window.history.go("url")` working ?
Or is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: better way would be to use anchor element instead of js solution

Comment: As far as I'm aware `history.go()` only accepts an `int` data type, so passing it a `string` data type will **never** work, I'm assuming it has a built in feature to check the data type of the given parameter using the`typeof`operator.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V According the docs in the link of my question it does

Comment: @GuidoG I've read up that it does, but it's partially supported, it doesn't work in all browsers. FYI W3Schools is not the best source of information, I suggest it for learning the bare bones, but for learning things like design patterns, etc. I suggest you look elsewhere, I know I'm bias to mdn, here's a link to their [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti I tried using an anchor but that does exact what I do not want, as described in my quesion. It reloads the page not fetches from the cache

Comment: @GuidoG I may have a solution... Bear with me... I'll write it out in an answer, although it may take a sec to do....